# JavaScript click stop start clock time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello having an issue of javascript clock timer start and stop functions.**

And i included my css, html and also javascript source code, i want the function is start and stop. i tried so many times but still cannot able to solve the issue's.

**Its very simple but its very hard for click start and click stop.**

Thanks

### any help?

```js
setInterval(function () {
 var currentTime = new Date(); 
 var hours = currentTime.getHours();
 var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
 var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(); 
 var period = "AM";
 var setTimeout = currentTime.getDate();
 
 if (setTimeout = clock) {
           currentTime = "pause";  
   
     
document.querySelector('clock').onclick = pause();    
     
 }
    
    
 if (hours >=12) {
     
     period = "PM";
     
 }
    
if (hours > 12) {
    
    hours = hours - 12;
    
}
    
if (seconds < 10) {
    
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
    
}
    
if (minutes < 10) {
    
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
    
}    
    
    
var clockTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period + "pause" + setTimeout;
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    clock.innerText = clockTime;

            
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
background: coral;

}



#clock {
   
 position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: teal;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
    
      
    
    
}
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the pause() defined please show it or make it. And why are you defining setTimeout keep some words reserved as later on you'll never know that it is user-defined or default one. And your assignin with single `=` use `===` instead

Comment: Hai,
I trying to set the click start time and stop time as well as its on the same div, so i trying to make it but cant understands it. boss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this much more involved than it need be.

First, you have to get a reference to the timer so that you can cancel it later if you wish (when the clock needs to be paused) using [`.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

And second, to display the time in the format you've chosen, you only need to use [`.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString). All of your code that deals with formatting the result can be removed.

See the comments inline below for details.

```js
// Get this reference, just once outside of the function that it will be needed in
// instead of on each invocation of the function.
let clock = document.getElementById('clock');
let timer = null;  // The timer variable is null until the clock initializes

// This is the modern way to set up events
clock.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // If the clock is ticking, pause it. If not, start it
  if(timer !== null){
    clearInterval(timer);  // Cancel the timer
    timer = null;  // Reset the timer because the clock is now not ticking.
  } else {
    timer = setInterval(runClock, 1000);
  }
});

// Get a reference to the timer and start the clock
timer = setInterval(runClock, 1000);

function runClock() {
    // .innerText is non-standard. Use .textContent instead.
    // .toLocaleTimeString() gets you the locale format of the time.
    clock.textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();            
}
```

```css
body { background: coral; }

#clock {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: teal;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks boss. I can trying to use modern way javascript.

Comment: @Dharmesh Vekariya Vendor prefixes for `transform` are not necessary as `transform` has been standard for 3 years now and is supported in all current (and previous generation) browsers. And ***if*** you were going to use them, the vendor prefixes should be listed first and the standard property should come after them for progressive enhancement. Also, editing someone else's post just to add this is an inappropriate use for the Edit privilege. Use Edit to correct typos or to make something more clear. Do not use Edit to alter code.

Answer (score 0):

Is just the order of variables. If you split and create functions it will be easier to handle it. First you should take the element clock outside of interval function, and second you should put setInterval as a function then it is possible to reuse and put in variables. the third is, put the interval in some variable because you can stop the event calling clearInterval.

```js
var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
var currentTime;
var pause = true;
var clockTime = 'paused';
clock.innerText = clockTime;

function initClock() {
  return setInterval(function () {
   currentTime = new Date(); 
   var hours = currentTime.getHours();
   var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
   var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(); 
   var period = "AM";
   var setTimeout = currentTime.getDate();
    
   if (hours >=12) {
     period = "PM";
   }

   if (hours > 12) {
     hours = hours - 12;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }    


  clockTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + period;
  clock.innerText = clockTime;
  }, 1000);
}

clock.onclick = function() {
  if(pause){
    theClock = initClock();
  } else {
    clockTime = 'paused';
    clock.innerText = clockTime;
    clearInterval(theClock);
 }
  pause = !pause;
};
```

```css
body {
background: coral;

}



#clock {
   
 position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: teal;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But When I stop the Timer its show's paused, what I need if I stop it has to show the stopped the timer.